# Нужен ли дефис между словами?

Tags: приложение

> Коллеги ( ) врачи, завтра у нас состоится собрание, всем быть!

Вроде бы "коллеги" является обращением, и поэтому дефис не нужен.
А если сказать без варианта обращения, нужен ли он будет тогда:
"Коллеги-врачи поприветствовали меня!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) ***Коллеги-врачи**, завтра у нас состоится собрание, всем быть!*

Это обращение, ***коллеги-врачи*** — сложносоставное слово, связь сочинительная однородная, по образцу "***друзья-приятели***".

(2) *Коллеги, **врачи**, поприветствовали меня!*

Здесь более уместным является обособленное приложение с **уточняющим** значением.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а почему так? Например, "братцы кролики" пишут без дефиса.

Comment: Вроде бы с дефисом:  https://russian_argo.academic.ru/966/братец-кролик

Comment: Мы можем переосмысливать подобные выражения, но иногда они имеют устойчивый характер. Раздельно: приложение + опр. слово;  дефис: опр слово + приложение;  дефис: сложносоставное слово (равноправные отношения).

Comment: а это пправило не действует? нарицательное существительное, выступающее в роли
официального обращения или упоминания, и следующее за ним
нарицательное или собственное имя

Comment: название фильма везде без дефиса былонаписано

Comment: Действует, но там определенная тематика:  господин посол, товарищ генерал и т.д., товарищ Петров и т.д.  А коллеги-врачи выглядит как разговорное сочетание.

Comment: Фильм? Тогда считайте, что братец кролик, братец – приложение, а кролик – опр. слово. Кстати, произношение разное, при дефисе слова произносятся слитно. Здесь много условности, надо смотреть, как принято писать, а объяснить все можно.

Comment: проосто мне непонятно, почему слово "коллеги" нельзя считать таким же обращением, как товарищ или господин, матушка, сестра?:

Comment: нашла в словаре Ефремовой. коллега м. и ж.

1. Человек одной профессии, товарищ по работе или по учебе в высшей школе.

2. Употр. как обращение.

Comment: Коллеги врачи?  Можно и так. Если произнести с паузой. Это более деловой стиль. а коллеги-врачи разговорный (коллеги и врачи), слитное произношение. Эти слова можно писать по слуху.  Но нужно ориентироваться и на словари,  конечно, только выбирать подходящий вариант.

Comment: в одном словаре нашла еще "коллеги-биологи", почему-то дефис везде с "коллегами".

Comment: Они и коллеги, и биологи, соч. связь, можно назвать и так, и так. Слитное произношение, равное ударение. Мне этот вариант кажется более уместным.

Comment: я бы тоже дефис написала, но в не в случае с прямым обращением: Коллеги биологи, разводите жаб. Коллеги-биологи разводят жаб.

Comment: Аможете еще подсказать. товарищ судья, сделайте перерыв. тут приложением будет судья или товарищ?

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Не забывайте, пожалуйста, не только принимать ответ галочкой, но и  отмечать вопросы и ответы стрелочкой. // И вы так и не ответили на мои комментарии...